# How to match full words?

Tags: php, regex, search

I use a simple `preg_match_all` to find the occurrence of a list of words in a text.

```
$pattern = '/(word1|word2|word3)/';
$num_found = preg_match_all( $pattern, $string, $matches );
```

But this also match subset of words like `abcword123`. I need it to find `word1`, `word2` and `word3` when they're occurring as full words only. Note that this doesn't always mean that they're separated by spaces on both sides, it could be a comma, semi-colon, period, exclamation mark, question mark, or another punctuation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IF you are looking to match "word1", "word2", "word3" etc only then using in_array is always better. Regex are super powerful but it takes a lot of cpu power also. So try to avoid it when ever possible

```
$words = array ("word1", "word2", "word3" );
$found = in_array ($string, $words);
```

check [PHP: in_array - Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) for more information on `in_array`

And if you want to use regex only try

```
$pattern = '/^(word1|word2|word3)$/';
$num_found = preg_match_all( $pattern, $string, $matches );
```

And if you want to get something like `"this statement has word1 in it"`, then use `"\b"`  like

```
$pattern = '/\b(word1|word2|word3)\b/';
$num_found = preg_match_all( $pattern, $string, $matches );
```

More of it here [PHP: Escape sequences - Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php) search for `\b`

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$pattern = '/\b(word1|word2|word3)\b/';
$num_found = preg_match_all( $pattern, $string, $matches );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `\b` to match word boundaries.  So you want to use `/\b(word1|word2|word3)\b/` as your regex.